# CodingBat Java exercise about word matching doesn't make sense

Tags: java, string

So the question goes like this:

> Given a string and a second "word" string, we'll say that the word matches the string if it appears at the front of the string, except its first char does not need to match exactly. On a match, return the front of the string, or otherwise return the empty string. So, so with the string "hippo" the word "hi" returns "hi" and "xip" returns "hip". The word will be at least length 1. "

First off, I have no clue what the question is even asking. Second, I looked up a solution to it and I don't get the solution either. Can someone help me comprehend what is even happening? Is there an alternate way of doing this?

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {
    if (str.length() < 1) {
       return "";
    }
    if (str.substring(1).indexOf(word.substring(1)) != 0) { // I am utterly confused here, wouldn't this always be true if it starts beyond zero?
        return "";
    }
       return str.substring(0, word.length());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tasked with seeing if a string, str, starts with word.  But you're not matching the first character.  That's why you use "1" to specify you want only the string and word starting the second character.  "0" would represent the first character.  The "indexOf" method of a string searches for an instance of the word you pass in, and returns the index..the character number... where the match was found.  So if it was found at the start..the first character... it'd return 0.  Because you chopped off the first character of both using substring, you're just looking for a match at character 0.

If the index was not found at 0 (-1 for not found, or greater than 0 for word being found, but not in the beginning of str), then it's returning an empty string.

A slight alteration would be to chop off only the first character of "word" and see if it's found at index 1 of str.  But it's simpler to chop off the first character of both and see if they line up at the start.

Another variation would be to do a "regex" pattern match, but that's going to be unnecessarily confusing for you.

```
Original str:  "woogie"
Original word: "goog"
```

Is it a match?

Hack off the first character:

```
Shortened str: "oogie"
Shortened word: "oog"
```

"oog" is found to start at position 0 of "oogie", so indexOf returns 0.

Comment: Ah, so the indexOf method counts the beginning of the substring as 0 even though you're starting it at 1 of the original?

Comment: Yep, because you hacked off the first character of the original, the second character of the original (index 1) becomes the first character (index 0).

Answer (score 2):

> First off, I have no clue what the question is even asking.

You have a first string and a second string (word).

The word matches the first string if

- The word matches the beginning of the first string.
- The word matches the beginning of the first string even if the first letter of the word doesn't match the first letter of the front string.

If the word matches the first string, return the first word length characters of the first string.  Otherwise, return an empty string.

The word will be at least length 1.

> Second, I looked up a solution to it and I don't get the solution either. Can someone help me comprehend what is even happening?

Here's my solution to startWord.  I hope it makes more sense.

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {
    String x = word.substring(1);
    if (str.startsWith(x, 1)) {
        return str.substring(0, word.length());
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {
  int len1 = str.length();
  int len2 = word.length();
  String withoutFirst = word.substring(1,len2);
  String result = "";
  if(len1>=len2 && len2>0){
   if(str.substring(0,len2).equals(word)){
     result = word;
     }else if(word.substring(1,len2).equals(str.substring(1,len2))){
      result = str.substring(0,1) + word.substring(1,len2);
    }
  }else{
   result = "";
  }
  return result;
}
```